How to add dynamic where code when use @Fetch to load the datas?
I'm using the framework "mybatis-mp" for development. The framework's URL is here.
Framework version: 1.5.8
VO class
@Data
@ResultEntity(SysUser.class)
public class SysUserVo {

    private Integer id;

    private String userName;

    private Integer roleId
    
 
    @ResultEntityField(property = "password")
    private String pwd;
    
    @Fetch(source = SysUser.class, property = "roleId", target = SysRole.class, targetProperty = "id")
    private SysRoleVo sysRole;
    
}

Query code
List<SysUserRoleVO> list = QueryChain.of(sysUserMapper)
        .like(SysUser::getUser,"ad") 
        .returnType(SysUserRoleVO.class)
        .list();

I want to load SysRole only when SysRole.type = 1. What can I do?

thank you,I'm had ask author,the Solution is :
List<SysUserRoleVO> list = QueryChain.of(sysUserMapper)
    .like(SysUser::getUser,"ad")
    .fetchFilter(SysUserRoleVO::getSysRole, where -> {
               where.eq(SysRole::getType, 0);
     }) 
    .returnType(SysUserRoleVO.class)
    .list();

the sql will be :SELECT * FROM sys_role WHERE id=? and type = 0
the function is need than 1.6.0 version

You can use a custom query or modify your "@Fetch" annotation logic. "mybatis-plus" does not directly support conditional fetching in annotations, so you will need to handle this in your query logic. I assume you have a mapper for SysRole. If so, fetch all roles with "type = 1" and then manually set the "SysRole" field in your "SysUserVo" objects. It should look something like this:
@Mapper
public interface SysRoleMapper {
    @Select("SELECT * FROM sys_role WHERE type = 1")
    List<SysRole> selectActiveRoles();
}

List<SysUserVo> list = QueryChain.of(sysUserMapper)
        .like(SysUser::getUser, "ad")
        .select(SysUser::getId, SysUser::getUserName, SysUser::getRoleId) 
        .list();

List<SysRole> activeRoles = sysRoleMapper.selectActiveRoles();
Map<Integer, SysRole> roleMap = activeRoles.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(SysRole::getId, Function.identity()));

list.forEach(user -> {
    SysRole role = roleMap.get(user.getRoleId());
    if (role != null) {
        user.setSysRole(new SysRoleVo(role));
    }
});


thank you,I'm had ask author,the Solution is :
List<SysUserRoleVO> list = QueryChain.of(sysUserMapper)         .like(SysUser::getUser,"ad")         .fetchFilter(SysUserRoleVO::getSysRole, where -> {                    where.eq(SysRole::getType, 0);          })          .returnType(SysUserRoleVO.class)         .list();
the sql will be :SELECT * FROM sys_role WHERE id=? and type = 0
the function is need than 1.6.0 version
